# Combining two dataframes with alternating column position

Tags: r, dataframe, cbind

**I have these two dataframes:**

```
df1 <- tibble(b = 1:4,
       a = 1:4,
       c = 1:4)

df2 <- tibble(b_B = 1:4,
              a_A = 1:4,
              c_C = 1:4)

> df1
# A tibble: 4 x 3
      b     a     c
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3
4     4     4     4
> df2
# A tibble: 4 x 3
    b_B   a_A   c_C
  <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3
4     4     4     4
```

I would like to combine this two dataframes keeping the column position of df1 and entering the columns of `df2` alternating with `df1`

**Desired output:**

```
  b b_B a a_A c c_C
1 1   1 1   1 1   1
2 2   2 2   2 2   2
3 3   3 3   3 3   3
4 4   4 4   4 4   4
```

**I have tried:**

```
cbind(df1, df2) %>% 
  select(gtools::mixedsort(colnames(.)))

  a a_A b b_B c c_C
1 1   1 1   1 1   1
2 2   2 2   2 2   2
3 3   3 3   3 3   3
4 4   4 4   4 4   4
```

But this orders the columns alphabetically.

Comment: Do you want `bind_cols(df1, df2) %>% dplyr::select(all_of(c(matrix(names(.), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))))`

Comment: `base` alternative: `cbind(df1, df2)[order(c(seq_along(df1), seq_along(df2)))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `matrix` route to bind the column names into a `dim` structure and then concatenate (`c`)

```
library(dplyr)
bind_cols(df1, df2) %>% 
   dplyr::select(all_of(c(matrix(names(.), ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE))))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 6
      b   b_B     a   a_A     c   c_C
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1     1     1     1     1     1     1
2     2     2     2     2     2     2
3     3     3     3     3     3     3
4     4     4     4     4     4     4
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, with `purrr::pmap_dfc`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

pmap_dfc(list(df1, df2, names(df1), names(df2)),
   ~ data.frame(..1, ..2) %>% set_names(c(..3, ..4)))

#>   b b_B a a_A c c_C
#> 1 1   1 1   1 1   1
#> 2 2   2 2   2 2   2
#> 3 3   3 3   3 3   3
#> 4 4   4 4   4 4   4
```

---

Or with:

```
bind_cols(df1, df2) %>% 
  relocate(map(1:ncol(df1), ~ c(.x, .x + ncol(df1))) %>% unlist())
```